# Embarcadero Deployment manager puts android assets in wrong remote path

Tags: android-notifications, c++builder, android-assets, c++builder-xe8, appmethod

I am trying to deploy a mp3 file within a C++Builder android Project using Deployment Manager. Was trying to give a scheduled TNotification a specific sound.

I tried to set `Remote Path` to `assets\` in Deployment manager, but the mp3 file was positioned in `/storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.embarcadero.myproject1/files/` on the android device... I expected it to be in `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/`

Is there a setting somewhere changing the assets directory ?

Or is this a bug in XE8, and I have to copy the file in my program to the correct destination?

Comment: Try `assets\internal\ `

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: [Creating an Android App - Loading and Deploying Files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)

Comment: This was one of the guides I checked, and I expected it to be in `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/`. Checked it on a Android 5.01, didn't find the file until I searched for it. The reason for `assets` is I want to reach the file from gcm push notification and from a scheduled TNotification. Did just test it from the location I found, it worked from the TNotification but not from the pushnotification.